# HAL_GetTick() crash mcu

Tags: gcc, embedded, stm32, hal, stm32f4

I created a simple project using STCubeMX for my nucleo-f446ZE(STM32F446ZET6).

The project should be a USB device HID but it fail to start. After messing around with the debugger, I discovered that the MCU PC register go to 0x00000000 or 0xFFFFFFFF or sometimes random invalid value.

I didn't modify any code. I compiled the code with MDK-ARM (modified GCC, Vision IDE), and with GCC (openSTM32) and the same thing happen.

Callstack :

- Main
- SystemClock_Config
- HAL_RCC_ClockConfig (632)
- Hal_GetTick

Ps:
RAM got corrupted after 0x080149A and that why the program do weird stuff
Image
[image: Debugger,assembly]

**Solution**

CubeMX didn't setup clocks very well. here is the setup i used to make work the usb.

```
  //RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  //RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  //RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 192;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
```

Comment: The default `HAL_GetTick()` implementation simply returns the counter value incremented in the SYSTICK interrupt. (but can be overridden - it is declared with "weak" linkage).  Use "step-into" with the disassembly window selected to step in at the assembly level.  Check also that you have sufficient stack allocated, and that the stack is not cirrupted (before or during the call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RCC_ClkInitStruct is probably not initialized properly (or at all)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I think the RCC_CLKInitStruct is ok. http://pastebin.com/RxQc2NSZ

Comment: Tips to go further. Disable optimization on stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c (right click on the file in project browser). The assembler output will be easier to understand. Seondly, find the source of your __HAL_RCC_SYSCLK_CONFIG macro, and work back which registry it should write to. Verify that the correct address is loaded into CPU registers.

Comment: (In the code following, MCU is probably configured to use external crystal. Are the defines for crystal MHz correctly setup in your project?)

Comment: When I change the system clock to PLL the MCU get corrupted because the PLL wasn't setup right. the PLL want to have HSE (which is 8MHz from ST/Link2 in nucleo) but CubeMX didn't want to select this (even if it tell you it's an error). Thank you so mush for helping me out